# Magento 1.9 - Transaction email - logo displayed broken

Tags: html, email, magento, gmail

I am looking for a way to display my logo in the transactional email.
This is not a duplicate question. Believe me I have tried everything in StackOverflow.

The problem is that I will give the correct url's:

```
<img src="http://scrapbooking.gr/media/email/logo/default/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend' }}" />
<img src="{{var logo_url}}"  style="float:right;"/>
```

I add both of them to see which one will work. Gmail will not display the correct url though.

```
<img class="CToWUd" style="float:right" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/VPnGMTbyVJ2OesSkQPq5…tp://scrapbooking.gr/media/email/logo/default/logo_email.gif"></img>
<img class="CToWUd" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/VPnGMTbyVJ2OesSkQPq5…tp://scrapbooking.gr/media/email/logo/default/logo_email.gif"></img>
```

I read that Gmail uses this googleusercontent feature for safer emails. But it is not supposed to mess up with the image url. 
Also, the htaccess is not password protected.

Comment: Google uses local cache for images, if the image is not showing up, that means that Google/Gmail cannot reach the server to retrieve the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few reasons this may have failed.

Your example of pure image test was not correctly coded, instead of this:

```
<img src="http://scrapbooking.gr/media/email/logo/default/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend' }}" />
```

it should be

```
<img src="http://scrapbooking.gr/media/email/logo/default/logo_email.gif" />
```

And two, stop testing with google. It does cache your images so you have no way of knowing what URL is actually being sent. Just use any other email client.

Some other perks of google's image caching mechanism is that it protects the users from submitting information to the sender (click rates, open rates) by caching the images. The downside is that, when caching, it requests these images using its servers and thus if you have an .httaccess IP block or using a Host file to load your website it will show those images as broken.

Another recent discovery of mine on broken images is that some web clients like outlook and thunderbird will show your images as broken if they are secure (have https in them).

Comment: Actually it was dut to the testing server I was working on. My site is not onlin but i see it with added IP in host file. Thanks though!

Comment: yup, this answer also applies to that scenario. Google will try to retrieve those images from the outside world and not hit them. Same if you block the site by IP. You will, however, see those images if you are using something like Thunderbird, outlook on your computer as those images are getting pulled using your computer's IP or your computer's host file.

Comment: Very nice suggestion. Good thought. Make it an answer using my comment and I will accept it.